# Imprimir variável no java

Tags: java, android

desculpa a ignorância, porem estou aprendendo sozinho e lendo bastante, estou no inicio,
preciso gerar uma senha calculando dia * mes * ano, criei a variavel que calcula isso porem não consigo fazer que apareça, deixei uma string onde deveria aparecer!

```
    package com.roberto.senhauniplus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void texto(View view){

        TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.gerarsenha);
        texto.setText(R.id.gerarsenha);
        texto.setText("quero que a senha apareça aqui"); // aqui onde o botão substitui o texto pela senha!
        int senha = dia*mes*ano; // aqui onde calcula (ainda não testei)


    }
    Date dataAtual = new Date();

    int dia = dataAtual.getDate();
    int mes = dataAtual.getMonth();
    int ano = dataAtual.getYear();

}
```

estou usando o android studio, tem um botão onde gera a senha funcionando certinho, realmente só falta imprimir a senha!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Cálculo da Senha:**
   Primeiro, você precisa calcular a senha multiplicando o dia, mês e ano atual. Você já tem a parte do cálculo no seu código. No entanto, o cálculo é feito fora do método `texto(View view)`. Mova o cálculo para dentro do método, pois é aí que você deseja gerar a senha.

```java
public void texto(View view) {
    Date dataAtual = new Date();
    int dia = dataAtual.getDate();
    int mes = dataAtual.getMonth();
    int ano = dataAtual.getYear();

    int senha = dia * (mes + 1) * (ano + 1900); // +1 para ajustar o mês e +1900 para ajustar o ano

    TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.gerarsenha);
    texto.setText("A senha é: " + senha);
}
```

2. **Atualização do TextView:**
   No trecho acima, a variável `senha` é calculada e armazenada. Em seguida, você atualiza o `TextView` com o texto contendo a senha. Use a função `setText()` para isso, assim como você já fez.

```java
texto.setText("A senha é: " + senha);
```

3. **Ajuste de Mês e Ano:**
   Note que usei `mes + 1` para ajustar o mês porque `Date.getMonth()` retorna um valor de 0 a 11 para representar os meses (janeiro é 0, fevereiro é 1, etc.). Além disso, adicionei 1900 a `ano` porque `Date.getYear()` retorna o ano atual - 1900.

Com essas alterações, quando o botão for clicado, o texto do `TextView` será atualizado com a senha calculada corretamente.

Lembre-se de que esta é uma abordagem simples para gerar senhas. Se você estiver considerando usar senhas mais seguras, é necessário adotar métodos mais robustos de geração e gerenciamento de senhas.

Answer (score -1):

System.out.println(“Seu texto é inserido aqui, entre aspas duplas”);

No caso da tua variável é System.out.println(senha);

Comment: então ficaria assim texto.setText(System.out.println(senha)); ? na verdade não esta aceitando essa variavel de qualquer maneira :(

Comment: desculpa a ignorância, realmente estou iniciando!

Answer (score -1):

Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, você só precisa colocar a variável senha no seu TextView...
para isso remova `texto.setText(R.id.gerarsenha);`
e coloque `texto.setText(senha);`

Ficaria assim:

```
public void texto(View view){
    TextView texto = findViewById(R.id.gerarsenha);
    int senha = dia*mes*ano; // aqui onde calcula (ainda não testei)
    texto.setText(senha);
}
```

Eu aconselharia a inicializar o TextView dentro do onCreate, você não precisa incializar ele sempre na ação do botão.

Uma forma mais organizada:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Date dataAtual;
    private int dia, mes, ano;
    private TextView texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Inicializa as variáveis
        dataAtual = new Date();
        dia = dataAtual.getDate();
        mes = dataAtual.getMonth();
        ano = dataAtual.getYear();
        texto = findViewById(R.id.gerarsenha);
    }

    public void texto(View view) {
        int senha = dia * mes * ano; // aqui onde calcula (ainda não testei)
        texto.setText(senha);
    }
}
```